# SQL Titanium using SQLite

Tags: mysql, titanium

I have a database look like this

[image: Database]

I'm trying to get the NamaHalaman by doing some sql Query

```
function getPageByMdl(modul) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Halaman WHERE ModulLayanan = '"+modul+"' ORDER BY Urutan ASC";
    var results = [];
    var sqlResultSet = db.execute(sql);
    while (sqlResultSet.isValidRow()) {
        results.push({
            namahalaman : sqlResultSet.fieldByName('NamaHalaman')
        });
        sqlResultSet.next();
    }

    sqlResultSet.close();
    return results;
}
```

However the result length always give me 0 although as you can see it has 2 value in it. Another problem also happen when i try to run

```
var sql = "SELECT Distinct ModulLayanan FROM Halaman Order ASC";
```

it only returned the first value from the database which is Whistleblowing system.

Oh here's my function on showing the result

```
function loadDetailModule() {
    data = getPageByMdl(modulTemp);
    if (data.length > 0) {
        var tableData = [];
        //get through each item
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var detailmodul = data[i];

            //create table row
            var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
                dataIndex : i,
                _title : detailmodul.namahalaman,
                hasChild : true,
                className : 'detailmodul_halaman',
                filter : detailmodul.namahalaman,
                height : 70,
                backgroundColor : '#fff',

            });

            //title label for row at index i
            var titleLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
                text : detailmodul.namahalaman,
                font : {
                    fontSize : 14,
                    fontWeight : ' bold'
                },
                left : 70,
                top : 10,
                height : 50,
                width : 210,
                color : '#232',
                dataIndex : i
            });

            row.add(titleLabel);

            //add our little icon to the left of the row
            var iconImage = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
                image : 'img/eggcooking.png',
                width : 50,
                height : 50,
                left : 10,
                top : 10
            });

            row.add(iconImage);

            //add the row to data array
            tableData.push(row);
        }
        // set the data to tableview's data
        detailModuleTable.data = tableData;
        detailModuleTable.show();
    } else {
        detailModuleTable.hide();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is because the Titanium does not refresh your Database when you run your application.

What you need is:
1. uninstall your application in emulator 
or 
2. you can change the database name

```
Titanium.Database.install('SLTemp.sqlite', 'SLTemp1');
var db = Ti.Database.open('SLTemp1');
```

to

```
Titanium.Database.install('SLTemp.sqlite', 'SLTemp');
var db = Ti.Database.open('SLTemp');
```